# how to fix arduino variable getting extra data in callback function?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp32

When using the mqtt callback function. I am getting extra characters and persisting characters on each run.

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  const char* STATE_OPEN = "OPEN";
  const char* STATE_CLOSE = "CLOSE";
  const char* STATE_STOP = "STOP";
  char* msg = (char*)payload;

  if(strcmp(topic, "office/shutter") == 0) {
    Serial.println(msg);
    Serial.print("Message:");

    if(strcmp(msg, STATE_OPEN) == 0) {
      digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
      shutterRunTime = currentMillis;
    }
    if(strcmp(msg, STATE_CLOSE) == 0) {
      digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
      shutterRunTime = currentMillis;
    }
    if(strcmp(msg, STATE_STOP) == 0) {
      digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
      shutterRunTime = currentMillis;
    }
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("-----------------------");
  if((currentMillis - shutterRunTime) >= shutterMaxRun) {
    digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
  }
  /* Clear the strings */
  memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
}
```

if I post on mqtt `CLOSE` it works. if I post on mqtt `OPEN`, I get `OPENr` if it is done before `CLOSE` or otherwise if its after I get `OPENE`

I have tried to null out the variable `msg` and even `memset` doesn't work. How do I get it to just give me the value of the payload. 
when I do a `Serial.print(length)` it gives me the correct of either `4` or `5` so I am confused on whats actually happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just cast the byte array `payload` to a char array and then treat it as a string (a null terminated char array)

When you call `Serial.println(msg)` println has no idea how long string is so will continue to read until it hits the first null it finds in memory. So far it sounds like you have got lucky and it's only been 1 or 2 bytes after the actual length of the incoming `payload` byte array.

If you want a string that just contains the payload, you should malloc a new char array that is `length` + 1 and make sure the last char in the new array is set to 0 (null).

You should probably include the null terminator in your const strings as well that way strcmp will work properly as well.

Comment: I am still quite new to arduino so I have tried to interpret what you have said. I have changed the consts to `const char* STATE_OPEN = "OPEN"+'\0';`.
I have also changed the payload assignment to
`char msg[length+1]; strcpy(msg,(char*)payload+'\0');`
is this what you meant? I am still getting the issue where it msg prints out `OPENr` or `OPENE` depending on the order i submit the mqtt message.

Comment: I suggest you find a basic "How to work with Strings in C" tutorial online.

Comment: so the solution I had for the payload bit was `char msg[length+1]; strcpy(msg,(char*)payload); msg[length] = 0;`